# Is there any reason why Eminem laughed at the end of Mockingbird?

Tags: rap, eminem

Enimen laughs at the end of his song [Mockingbird](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S9bCLPwzSC0). During this song, he explains his problems (and makes most people cry).

Did he ever explain why he laughed? It's strange for someone to laugh at the end of an emotional song?

I'm thinking this was either him laughing at what he says about the jeweler

> I'll go back to the jewler who sold it to ya
>   and make him eat every carat, don't f*** with Dad.

and his pun.

This was also the during the time Eminem started abusing drugs, so I wonder if that might the case (sorry).

Comment: Does he laugh like a mockingbird ?

Answer (score 2):

I think he really does laugh because of that last line. I also think that it could mean that in spite of all the sad things, one should try not to lose their humour and still find things to laugh about. Otherwise - why would someone want to live any longer when there is nothing but pain and tragic?